# Codeiginter: SQL join causing duplicate results

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

I am trying to expand my knowledge, and building a mini-forum. Though, i have a problem with my code.

On the forum index page, i would like to display all the forum-categories with sub-categories, like this:

Category 1

- sub-category 1
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 3

Category 2

- sub-category 4
- sub-category 5
- sub-category 6

As you see, it's kinda the normal "forum-style".

But, when i'm fetching the results from th database, it's returning duplicate resultat. In this case, duplicate "Forum categories". So it looks like this:

Category 1

- sub-category 1

Category 1

- sub-category 2

Category 1

- sub-category 3

... and so on

Here is my Model that fetches all the categories etc:
categories.php

```
function GetCategories()
{   
   $this->db->select('*, categories.title as cat_title')->from('categories')->        join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.categorie_id = categories.id');
    $categories = $this->db->get();
    print_r($categories->result());
    return $categories;
}
```

and my Forum controller:

```
    function index()
{
    $data['categories'] = $this->categories->GetCategories();
    $this->load->view('forum/index', $data);
}
```

And the view

```
<div class="forum-body">
<?php 
foreach($categories->result() as $cate)
{
    echo '<div class="categorie-head">'.$cate->cat_title.'</div>';
    ?>
        <div class="categories-body">
            <?php echo $cate->title;?>
        </div>
        <?php
}
?>
```

**Table structure**

Table "catgories"

- id
- title

Table "sub_categories"

- id
- title
- categorie_id

So, what is the easiset wa yto fix it? Is it possible with onlly one query?

Please let me know if you don't understand :)

Comment: what is your Table structure?without knowing table structure it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. Let me edit and insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="forum-body">
<?php 
$cat_title = '';
foreach($categories->result() as $cate)
{
   if($cat_title != $cate->cat_title)
    echo '<div class="categorie-head">'.($cat_title = $cate->cat_title).'</div>';
    ?>
        <div class="categories-body">
            <?php echo $cate->title;?>
        </div>
        <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem right" doesn't explain HOW it doesn't seem right!!! In your code you were writing out the cat_title on every iteration of the loop. My change means that you only get it for new cat_title values. If it is still not right you have to give us more of a clue than "it is wrong"!!!!!

Comment: Well, if you look at the link i send you see what's wrong. I have duplicate "Category 1".

Comment: You need to ORDER your query BY categories.title, sub_categories.title to get them in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

It is very probable that the results of your query show something like:

```
Category 1  | sub-category 1
Category 1  | sub-category 2
Category 1  | sub-category 3
Category 2  | sub-category 4
Category 2  | sub-category 5
Category 2  | sub-category 6
...
```

Just know how to properly display it in the view. It can resulver in several ways. For example concatenating the subcategories grouped by category or with some "IF" logic in PHP:

```
<div class="forum-body">
<?php
$cat_main = ''; 
foreach($categories->result() as $cate)
{
    $cat_main = ($cat_main == $cate->cat_title) ? '' : $cate->cat_title; 
    if($cat_main != '') '<div class="categorie-head">'.$cate->cat_title.'</div>'; 
?>
        <div class="categories-body">
            <?php echo $cate->title;?>
        </div>
<?php  }  ?>
```